# Resuming threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading

This is what I want to accomplish!

step 1) Start th1 and go to its runnable

step 2) start th2 inside the runnable of th1

step 3) in the middle of the runnable, join th2 and go to the runnable of th2

step 4) in the middle of the runnable of th2, join th1 and go back to exactly where I left in th1 runnable

step 5) after th1 runnable is done, return to th2 runnable exactly where I left and finish the th2 runnable

step 6) program ends

Steps 4 and 5 are my issue. I can't properly execute them.

```
public class Threads2 {
    class alphabet1 implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            alphabet2 alpha2= new alphabet2();
            Thread th2 = new Thread(alpha2);
            System.out.println("A");
            System.out.println("B");
            System.out.println("C");
            System.out.println("D");

            th2.start();
            try {
                th2.join();
            }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }catch (IllegalMonitorStateException e1){
                System.out.println("Thread interrupted!");
            }

            System.out.println("G");
            System.out.println("H");
        }
    }
    class alphabet2 implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            alphabet alpha= new alphabet();
            Thread th1 = new Thread(alpha);
            System.out.println("E");
            System.out.println("F");

            try {
                th1.join();
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
            }catch (IllegalMonitorStateException e1){
                System.out.println("Thread interrupted!");
            }

            System.out.println("I");

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Threads2 obj = new Threads2();

        alphabet1 alpha  = obj.new alphabet1(); 

        Thread th1 = new Thread(alpha);
        th1.start();

    }
}
```

OUTPUT:
A
B
C
D
E
F
I
G
H

"I" should be the last in the output. I know why it's displaying in the incorrect order, however, I can't figure out how to display it in the correct order? I've used notify() and wait() together. If I type "th1.start()" inside "alphabet2" then after "alphabet" class will restart with printing "A". I've tried "interrupt()" and "sleep()" as well. I understand my code has flaws, I'm just using the code as an example.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can I print out the alphabets in order

Comment: `System.out.println("A B C D E F G H I");`

Comment: Yes, I could do that in one line, but the point is to do it with certain alphabets split up. How can I reorder it by using threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution based on your code.

```
public class Main {

    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        alphabet1 alpha = new alphabet1();
        new Thread(alpha).start();
    }

    static class alphabet1 implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            System.out.println("A");
            System.out.println("B");
            System.out.println("C");
            System.out.println("D");

            try {
                synchronized (LOCK) {
                    alphabet2 alpha2 = new alphabet2();
                    new Thread(alpha2).start();
                    LOCK.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException | IllegalMonitorStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("G");
            System.out.println("H");

            try {
                synchronized (LOCK) {
                    LOCK.notifyAll();
                }
            } catch (IllegalMonitorStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    static class alphabet2 implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            System.out.println("E");
            System.out.println("F");

            try {
                synchronized (LOCK) {
                    LOCK.notifyAll();
                    LOCK.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException | IllegalMonitorStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("I");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it! That's perfect! Unfortunately, I'm not able to cast a vote but you did a great job!

Comment: @ezg But do you understand why and how it works, and why yours is not working? Copy-pasting it in your homework is just a temporary fix...

Comment: No, I don't. But I'll have to research it. This isn't really for my homework, it's more for me anyways.

Comment: @ezg - you *can* accept answers that best answer your question

Comment: @ezg If you don't understand something don't hesitate to ask. And as krease has pointed out you can accept the answer.